# Visual Studio QueryFirst Extension

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, query-first

To those, who use QueryFirst ( https://www.codeproject.com/tips/1108776/queryfirst-world-first-implementation-of-the-domin )

How to connect it to a Wampserver MySQL database? I have connected the db to my project with

> Connect to Database

in

> Server Explorer

But with the Connect icon of QueryFirst I cannot attach my db to Query1.sql.

Comment: If you're talking about the Connect icon top left in the TSQL editor window, this can only connect to SQL Server. This limitation is common to all .sql files and doesn't have anything strictly to do with QueryFirst.

Answer (score 0):

1. You will need to create a connection string called QfDefaultConnection in your app or web.config.
2. specify the ADO provider MySql (providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient") are supported. This data source will be used at design time to retrieve the schema. At runtime.
3. you need to supply a class, QfRuntimeConnection, with a static method GetConnection(). You must supply this class, but you can always manage the connection yourself if you have other ideas. The compiler will show you the way !

Here is a sample for your reference.

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlvaNEnglADDgQU4I1v9w2nMEIS2

Answer (score 0):

In your app.config, you'll need a connection string like this...

```
<add name="QfDefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=dbname;Uid=root;Pwd=Dimosoftware=1;AllowUserVariables=True;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"></add>
```

and code...

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace YourApp
{
    class QfRuntimeConnection
    {
        public static IDbConnection GetConnection()
        {
            return new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["QfDefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
        }
    }
}
```